# "Could not convert string to float" Error when working with CSV Data in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, csv

I am trying to implement logistic regression on a dataset which is stored in CSV format, however despite implementing this exactly the way an example online did, apparently my data has not been converted into a format where it can be worked with numerically.

I usually only use c++/java, so all this python syntax and the functions for working with these datasets have been quite confusing for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report


def calc_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]
    
    if pd.isnull(Age):

        if Pclass == 1:
            return 37

        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29

        else:
            return 24

    else:
        return Age

def driverMain():
    train = pd.read_csv('/Users/krishanbansal/Downloads/LogisticRegression-master/titanic_train.csv')
    test = pd.read_csv('/Users/krishanbansal/Downloads/LogisticRegression-master/titanic_test.csv')
    
    
    sns.heatmap(test.isnull(),yticklabels=False,cbar=False,cmap='viridis')
    
    train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(calc_age,axis=1)
    test['Age'] = test[['Age','Pclass']].apply(calc_age,axis=1)
  
    sex = pd.get_dummies(train['Sex'],drop_first=True)
    embark = pd.get_dummies(train['Embarked'],drop_first=True)
    train.drop(['Sex','Embarked','Name','Ticket'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    train = pd.concat([train,sex,embark],axis=1)
    train.head()
    
    train.drop(['male','Q','S'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    
    sns.heatmap(train.isnull(),yticklabels=False,cbar=False,cmap='viridis')

    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train.drop('Survived',axis=1),train['Survived'], test_size=0.20,random_state=101)
    
    logmodel = LogisticRegression()
    logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
    predictions = logmodel.predict(X_test)
    
    print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))
    print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driverMain()
```

[image: Error]

Comment: What numeric value do you expect `E17` to correspond to?

Comment: @BigBen I don't know because I don't have any variable named E17, I believe it was supposed to be a function that is approximated by the logistic regression. not a single numerical value.

Comment: you can open your `csv` and check what is there in `E17`

Comment: `fit` requires that the inputs be float dtype arrays, or something it can convert with `np.asarray(...)`.  You  are passing it pandas dataframes (hence the final traceback is `np.asarray(self.values, dtype)`.  You'll need to examine `train`.  Actually you did run `head(train)`, but forgot to show it to us (or for some perverse reason thought it wasn't relevant to the problem).

Comment: @hpaulj I thought when I used get_dummies and concated all the dummy variables into train that would allow me to use the data with the logistic regression model. I also tried to convert X_train to an array using np.asarray(), but that didn't fix it. I ran head(train), and to me it looks normal, but maybe I should have posted it.

Comment: did it have float dtype colunns, or object?  Object can hold strings, lists or other things.  I don't use pandas enough to know what your 'dummies' etc does.

Comment: In contrast to your other languages, typing in python is dynamic.  The type of a variable is the type of the object assigned to it.  Arrays also have a `dtype`.  `pandas` also uses `dtype` for its columns, but it change that on the fly.  So even if you create a frame that's all float, assigning or concatenating strings can change them to object.  Since you data come from `csv`s we can't reproduce or test your code.

Comment: Maybe `head()` isn't the most useful.  I'd like something like `dtypes` or `info` that tells us ABOUT the columns.

Comment: I fixed it, had to eliminate non numerics from the dataframe and create dummy variables.

Answer (score 0):

This error may come from some values in your dataset that are written in scientific notation, e.g `1E17`. In python you would normally write scientific notation as `1e17`, so maybe the interpreter doesn't do the conversion to float for you when storing the data.

You may want to check your dataset and do the proper conversions wherever needed.

Comment: Or, it could be a cabin number.

Comment: @JustLearning I checked in the training data set and E17 is passenger sex, so they are strings. I guess I have to figure out how to get rid of that part somehow.

Comment: Oh ahha right :)